# Multiple column lookup between sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets in excel, with 10 column but with different data. I want to compare both the sheets and highlight the difference based on values of 4 specific columns. For example,

Sheet 1:

```
id name address pincode
1   AA   XXX     123
```

Sheet 2:

```
id name address pincode
2   BB   YYY     345
1   AA   XXX     123
```

On comparing the above data, I want the common row in both the sheets to be highlighted with a colour.

How can I do this in excel?

Cheers

Comment: COUNTIFS, Array formula, how do you want it, on sheet 3? can you provide more info.  So you could use CF with Countifs() to highlight maybe, with no need for code??  based around this if(countifs(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!C:C,Sheet1!C1)>0 .......

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Answer (score 0):

To Check if 2 Rows are equal, you can use:

```
If Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Sheets("sheet1").Rows(3).Value)), Chr(0)) = _
   Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Sheets("sheet2").Rows(4).Value)), Chr(0)) Then

    Sheets("sheet1").Rows(3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Sheets("sheet2").Rows(4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

Where you have to replace "sheet1" and "sheet2" with your sheet names and adjust the rows. If the Rows are equal to each other, they will be highlighted red.

If you are using this, you would have to compare each row of the first sheet with each row of the second sheet, which might be very slow

Example:

```
Dim usedRange1 As Integer
Dim usedRange2 As Integer

usedRange1 = Sheets("sheet1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
usedRange2 = Sheets("sheet2").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To usedRange1 Step 1

    'Check if row in sheet1 is not empty
    If Application.CountA(Sheets("sheet1").Rows(i)) <> 0 Then

        For j = 1 To usedRange2 Step 1

            'check if row in sheet2 is not empty
            If Application.CountA(Sheets("sheet2").Rows(j)) <> 0 Then

                If Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Sheets("sheet1").Rows(i).Value)), Chr(0)) = _
                    Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Sheets("sheet2").Rows(j).Value)), Chr(0)) Then

                    Sheets("sheet1").Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Sheets("sheet2").Rows(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: It will just work if the two Rows are completely equal, so if a column is empty, it won't, then you have to  compare the columns manually, but you can keep the loop, just change the if condition